# I want to show 3d model on pyqt

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt

I want to display 3d model on my desktop application.
This is opengl code:
(I deleted some code on class bcs ı could not share without it so this code is work)

```
class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.qglClearColor(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))  # initialize the screen to blue
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)  # enable depth testing

        self.initGeometry()

        self.rotX = 15
        self.rotY = 40
        self.rotZ = 40

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        aspect = width / float(height)

        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 1.0, 100.0)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)

    def initGeometry(self):
        self.cubeVtxArray = np.array(
            [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
             [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
             [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
             [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
             [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
             [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
             [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
             [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
        self.vertVBO = vbo.VBO(np.reshape(self.cubeVtxArray,
                                          (1, -1)).astype(np.float32))
        self.vertVBO.bind()

        self.cubeClrArray = np.array(
            [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
             [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
             [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
             [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
             [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
             [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
             [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
             [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
        self.colorVBO = vbo.VBO(np.reshape(self.cubeClrArray,
                                           (1, -1)).astype(np.float32))
        self.colorVBO.bind()

        self.cubeIdxArray = np.array(
            [0, 1, 2, 3,
             3, 2, 6, 7,
             1, 0, 4, 5,
             2, 1, 5, 6,
             0, 3, 7, 4,
             7, 6, 5, 4])

    def setRotX(self, val):
        self.rotX = np.pi * val

    def setRotY(self, val):
        self.rotY = np.pi * val

    def setRotZ(self, val):
        self.rotZ = np.pi * val

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello OpenGL App')
        glWidget = GLWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(glWidget)
```

Result:

[image]

This is my main desktop application. I want to display 3d model on 3d widget.
How can I do?
If I promete the 3d widget and make the filename the same as the name I promete.Does it work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "promete"? Also, QGLWidget is deprecated, you should use [QOpenGLWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html).

Comment: Okey thanks, but how can I integrated GLWıdget class to QOpenGLWidget. can you summarize